# my internet gets slower over time, i get error messages,

Tags: internet, cable, splitter

i have cable internet, and  i use a splitter to separate the cables from my tv. my internet, which has been working fine until the past few days. now it starts off fine in internet explorer, but it soon slows to a crawl, gets sluggish, and i get error messages. i rebooted internet explorer, defragged my computer and scanned for viruses and malware.

is there a problem with my cables running to my modem from the cable outlet, or is it a problem with my computer (it is 8 years old)???

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

It is doubtful that it is your cables running to your modem.  You need to do a deeper analysis of when or what causes the slow down.  Does the computer feel faster when you restart, then seems to slow down, or do you have to reboot the router?  Do all sites feel slow or sluggish, or is it certain sites?  Is it time based, does it feel fast in the morning then slows down in the afternoon?  Cable modem share bandwidth between users so it could be other users taking up more bandwidth.  There are too many possibilities to give you a definite answer, but these tips should help you pinpoint the issue more clearly.

Comment: This is great, but it is not an answer (the question is too vague, I agree). I see this as a comment.